# Can we found mathematics without evaluation or membership?

Tags: reference-request, logic, set-theory, category-theory, foundations

In some sense, composition generalizes evaluation. The trick is, instead of writing $f(x)$ for $x$ an element of the domain of $X,$ we write $f \circ x$ for $x$ a function $1 \rightarrow X$. Similarly, inclusion generalizes membership (in some sense). The idea is that instead of writing $x \in X$ and calling $x$ an element, we write $x \subseteq X$ and demand that $x$ be a singleton.

Now these observations wouldn't be so interesting if composition/inclusion were ill-behaved relative to evaluation/membership. If anything, though, the opposite is true. In particular:

1. composition is associative, evaluation is not.
2. inclusion is transitive, membership is not.

Of course, the evaluation/membership duo is partially redeemed by its good extensionality properties. In particular:

- If $f$ and $g$ have domain $X$, then if for all $x \in X$ we have $f(x)=g(x)$ , then $f=g$.
- If $A,B \subseteq X,$ then if for all $x \in X$ we have $x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B$, then $A=B$.

However, we can rehash the above observations (or axioms or whatever) into statements involving only composition/inclusion.

- If $f$ and $g$ have domain $X$, then if for all $x : 1 \rightarrow X$ we have $f \circ x=g \circ x$ , then $f=g$.
- If $A,B \subseteq X$, then if for all singletons $x \subseteq X$ we have $x \subseteq A \leftrightarrow x \subseteq B$, then $A=B$.

So, I'm wondering: **can we found mathematics without using the notions of evaluation/membership?**

I know for example that categorial set theories like [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) make a big leap in this direction. However, as far as I know, all such theories are still based on classical first-order logic. Thus, we have expressions like $g \circ f$, which basically denote the function $\circ$ being evaluated at $(g,f).$ So, we haven't completely banished evaluation, just lessensed its prominence.

Furthermore, first-order logic also features expressions like $\forall x Px.$ However, this is conceptually equivalent to an expression like $\forall(P).$ Basically, we're thinking of $\forall$ is a function $\mathrm{Predicates} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$, that accepts a predicate $P$, and returns a truthvalue $\forall(P),$ which is true iff $P$ returns true on all possible inputs. So in some sense, the expression $\forall x Px,$ being essentially the same as $\forall(P),$ still involves evaluation. I'd rather have something more like $\forall \circ P,$ whatever that means.

In summary, I'm curious to know: is it possible to found mathematics in a way that makes absolutely no use of evaluation or membership, even at the level of the logic?

Comment: Well, we can think of any con- or disjunction (or any other logical connective) as being an evaluation. And without logical connectives, building up mathematics will be... difficult. You'd essentially be studying every statement in complete isolation. As a teacher of mine (a proponent of category theory) once said: "The theory of vector spaces would be very dull if it'd stop once we had proven the dimension theorem."

Comment: @Lord_Farin, its certainly true that $\wedge$ is an operator (function, connective, whatever). But could $X \wedge Y$ not be viewed as a composition $(\wedge) \circ (X,Y)$ or something? Of course, we now have the issue that $\circ$ is participating in an evaluation. That doesn't mean this issue is insurmountable though, it just means that I don't know how to surmount it.

Comment: It's certainly an interesting thought. Type-theoretically, this approach means that we treat $\land$ as a collection of operators $\land^X$, one for each function space (i.e. $\land^X: {\rm Prop}^X \times {\rm Prop}^X \to {\rm Prop}^X$) and cannot use the canonical binary operator $\land$ on $\rm{Prop}$ -- not to mention the case where $X$ and $Y$ have different domains. This seems a core issue that has to be addressed for this approach to possibly work. I don't know if this is possible, but it seemed good to at least bring it to your attention.

Comment: @user18921 it's not so clear to me: are you looking for some sort of foundational theory that doesn't have function symbol and membership-predicate?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, more like a foundational theory where we write $f \circ x$ rather than $f(x)$ and $x \subseteq X$ rather than $x \in X.$ Does that help?

Comment: @user18921 Then it's not so clear to me, why ETCS is not good?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, it *is* good. But its based on first-order logic. In FOL, we write $f(x),$ not $f \circ x$.

Comment: @user18921 still not getting: it's true that in FOL you write function application as $f(x)$ but then you can interpret that as the composition of a morphisms $x \colon \{\emptyset\} \to X$ to a $f \colon X \to Y$. So it's just a matter of syntax.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa, you might be right. If a logic supports the application of functions to functions, then there's a big difference, e.g. $(fg)x$ is different from $f(gx)$ if by concatenation we mean evaluation, but the same if we mean composition. However, since in FOL there is no chance to apply a function to a function, I'm beginning to think that the difference between $f(x)$ and $f \circ x$ may be merely notational.

Comment: @user18921 ok, Now I think I can get you an answer :) Wait for updates.

Comment: @user18921: Have you seen the category theoretic notion of "generalized elements"? A generalized element of $X$ is (given by) an arrow with codomain $X$. If $f : X \to Y$, then $f(x)$ is *defined* to mean (the generalized element of $Y$ given by) the composite $f \circ x$

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so basically I now think I get what you wanted.

Actually you can use ETCS as foundational theory (to be exact to have a theory that is completely equivalent to ZFC, which most people consider the basic foundational theory, you need to ad another axiom which plays the role of replacement axiom).

The idea to codify all the object of a (multisorted)-first order language in the following way:

- sorts of the theory are interpreted as object (i.e. sets) in the category;
- every constant symbol $c$ of type $X$ is interpreted as a morphisms (i.e. a function) of type $c \colon \bullet \to X$ (here $\bullet$ denote the singleton);
- every function symbol $f$ of type $A \to B$ is just a morphism $f \in \mathbf{Set}(A,B)$;
- a relation $R$ of type $A_1,\dots,A_n$ is interpreted as subobjects i.e. monomorphisms $r \colon R \hookrightarrow A_1 \times \dots \times A_n$.

Then all the logical operation can be codified as operation on such object via limits and colimits which are provided in the category of sets.

In such framework a term of type $f(c)$, where $f$ is a function symbol of type $A \to B$ and $c$ is a constant of type $X$, is the morphism $f \circ x \colon \bullet \to Y$, which is again a constant.

Membership can be codified too in a different sort of way.

The idea is that every *set* must be a subset of some *sort*, meaning that we want to identify sets with the unary predicates defining them.
Using this fact we can interpret sets of elements of type $X$ as monomorphism of type

$$p \colon P \hookrightarrow X$$

with this in mind a constant $c \colon \bullet to X$ belong to $P$ iff there's a morphism in $\mathbf{Set}$, let's call it $\tilde x \colon \bullet \to P$ such that $x = p \circ \tilde x$.
In this way we can defined $x \in P$ as an abbreviation for $\exists \tilde x \colon \bullet \to P \ x = p \circ \tilde x$.

The interesting fact about all this construction is that it can be done not just in the category of sets,(i.e. in the theory ETCS) but also in the theory of every other category with enough structure, for instance in every topos.

I think you could find interesting the following links

- [categorical semantics](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+semantics)
- [topos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos)
- [internal logic](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic)

about ETCS you may find interesting [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543) of Leinster.

**Edit:** An additional information, when dealing with the axiomatic theory ETCS you can avoid the use of the function symbol $\circ$ and use instead a ternary relation $\circ(x,y,z)$ which should be interpreted as $z$ is the composite of $x$ and $y$ (i.e. as $y \circ x = z$). Then you have to rephrase all the other axioms for category with this ternary relation (the axioms of associativity, identity, those that tell when the composition has sense). In such theory you cannot build terms via composition, so you don't have any *application* of functions. Of course you can reintroduce application/composition as symbolic abbreviation for the formulas build from the $\circ(x,y,z)$ with the connectives.